# How do I tell the listings package that comment characters only take effect at the start of a line?

Tags: listings

I'm trying to use the `listings` package to format a primitive, line-oriented, DSL. The language has three types of line: comment, command, and data.

Here's an MWE that 'works but not quite':

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  frame=single,
  morecomment=[l][\color{green}]{*},
  morecomment=[l][\color{red}]{\#},
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
* A comment
* A # comment
# A command
# A * command
  Data
  Some # data
  Some * data
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

resulting in this:

[image: Partially correct output]

Now, I need to stop the interpretation of # and * in data as starting comments, so I tried to use the `morecomment=[f]` option to replace my `[l]` options:

```
  morecomment=[f][0][\color{green}]{*},
  morecomment=[f][0][\color{red}]{\#},
```

but this now stops on the first line of the listing, with

```
! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>  \protect  l.13
*
     A comment ?
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need

```
  morecomment=[f][\color{green}][0]{*},
  morecomment=[f][\color{red}][0]{\#},
```

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  frame=single,
  morecomment=[f][\color{green}][0]{*},
  morecomment=[f][\color{red}][0]{\#},
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
* A comment
* A # comment
# A command
# A * command
  Data
  Some # data
  Some * data
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "You're almost there" -- that's too kind, thank you!